# I do not get any websocket messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I am in [the javascript room](http://javascriptroom.com) and I tried posting a message and got no response and I thought it weird, so I refreshed the page, and to my suprise there were quite a few new messages. So I tried posting again (which did work), but I **still** got no new messages until I refreshed -

What could be going on?

---

#### Update:

*Seems* to be working now, but what could have happened?

---

### Update 2:

***Nope***, not working again...

---

## Update 3:

I am not even getting updates on any comments or answers to my posts until I refresh the page.

This is my browser Information:

```
Google Chrome   23.0.1271.97 (Official Build 171054) m
OS  Windows
WebKit  537.11 (@136278)
JavaScript  V8 3.13.7.5
Flash   11.5.31.5
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
```

Comment: Works for me in IE9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're making some pretty large changes with our core network infrastructure. Sockets did go out for awhile but have been restored.  We'll keep an eye on it!

Comment: Ahhh thanky... Twas very annoying (especially in chat...)